# Sum of values of a column is different when plotted on a seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

i have a dataframe that has a column with no. of vehicles(count) at a certain station. the code gives the correct sum of this column, when i plot it on the seaborn barplot it is giving the wrong value.

```py
# this is the dataframe
ac=df_ras_1.loc[(df_ras_1['ENTRY_STATION']=='Ras') & (df_ras_1['EXIT_STATION']=='Ps')&(df_ras_1['VEHICLETYPE']=='Car')]

# sum of VEHICLETYPE
ac['VEH_COUNT'].sum()  ##gives the right value
391992

# when plotted it on the graph shows 
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

cp = sns.barplot(x="EXIT_STATION", y='VEH_COUNT',hue="VEHICLETYPE", data=ac)
```

[link to the graph](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ihqIzZVCt88EjSVbo3lNjnkWPv4i9xUh) this graph should give 391992, but its giving different value

Dataframe sample(df_ras_1) from which df 'ac' is made

```
DATE        ENTRY_STATION    EXIT_STATION   VEHICLETYPE  VEH_COUNT
2016-01-01  Ras              Ps             Car          1  
2016-01-02  Ras              Ps             Car          9  
2016-01-03  Ras              Ps             Car          12 
2016-01-04  Ras              Ps             Car          3
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? I.e. something that people can copy and immediately execute to reproduce the problem? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a guide

Comment: i have added the minimal example

Comment: For the minimal, sample Dataframe, please provide the expected result (25?) and what the plot yields

Comment: @Chowdry Okay, if I understand correctly, you don't make any use of 'DATE', is that right?

Comment: yeah. i dont need to display date on the barplot so i am not selecting'DATE'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's just say you have this following dataframe:

```
data = {'ENTRY': ['Ras', 'Ras', 'Ras', 'Mordor', 'Mordor'],
    'EXIT': ['Ps', 'Ps', 'Ps', 'Ps', 'Sky'],
    'TYPE': ['Car', 'Car', 'Car', 'Car', 'Car'],
    'VEH_COUNT': [1, 9, 12, 3, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.head()


#    ENTRY  EXIT    TYPE    VEH_COUNT
#0  Ras      Ps      Car    1
#1  Ras      Ps      Car    9
#2  Ras      Ps      Car    12
#3  Mordor   Ps      Car    3
#4  Mordor   Sky     Car    7
```

I would recommend you to use **groupby()** and **sum()** to make your data more clear and easier to both analyse and visualise.

```
df_grp = df.groupby(['ENTRY', 'EXIT', 'TYPE'])['VEH_COUNT'].sum().reset_index()
df_grp.head()


#   ENTRY   EXIT    TYPE    VEH_COUNT
#0  Mordor  Ps      Car      3
#1  Mordor  Sky     Car      7
#2  Ras     Ps      Car      22
```

As a result, you can easily plot charts based on your requirements.

```
# Seaborn Visualisation
ax = sns.barplot(x='EXIT', y='VEH_COUNT', data=df_grp)
```

[image]

You might notice that the value of *Ps* is now *12.5*. That's because it calculates the mean of *VEH_COUNT* from *ROW#0 and ROW#2*.

Therefore 22 + 3 = 25, then 25 / 2 = **12.5**

Whereas *the EXIT Sky* stays the same since it has only one value

---

Finally, to solve your problem, you can add **estimator=sum**

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='EXIT', y='VEH_COUNT', data=df_grp, ci=None, estimator=sum)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the response. Actually i have done it using groupby too. and it is giving the right sum on the graph. what's _really confusing_ is that using `loc`it gives the correct sum, as in the question, `ac['VEH_COUNT'].sum()  # ans 391992`, **but** different value on the graph. Why is that? I was trying to get the same output from both techniques.

Comment: @Chowdry sns.barplot will generate values based on means if there are multiple values to be calculated as default. Therefore, we can fix it by adding 'estimator=sum'.

Comment: Ohh!!! just tried 'estimator=sum' with the df obtained from 'loc'. It gave the right value on the graph. Dude you're good. thanks